# add quotation after autocomplete

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, autocomplete

I use android studio to edit my layouts in XML.
I use autocomplete.
My problem is android studio does not insert "" automatically.
for example if I use autocomplete to add `stateListAnimatior` it will add `android:stateListAnimator=` but I want `android:stateListAnimator=""` (With double quotes and focus in between them``.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to settings (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`S`)
2. Smart keys
3. Turn on `` Add quote for attribute value on typing `=` and attribute completion ``